# gridview formatstring value cannot be found and insert to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which looks like this.

[image]

ASP NET:

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="1000px" Height="91px" 
       AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataSourceID="orders" 
        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
        HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
            SortExpression="ProductID" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
            SortExpression="Name" >
            </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" 
            SortExpression="Price" DataFormatString="Php {0:0.00}" HtmlEncode="False" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
            SortExpression="Quantity" >
        </asp:BoundField>

       <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
            SortExpression="Amount" DataFormatString="Php {0:0.00}" >
        </asp:BoundField>

    </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />

<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></RowStyle>

</asp:GridView>
```

CODE for insert:
 C#

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        //string RefNo = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
        string ProductID = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
        string Name = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        decimal Price = decimal.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text);
        int Quantity = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text);
        string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
        //string Status = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[6].Text;

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SODetails (SOID, ProductID, Price, Quantity, Amount, Name) " +
            "VALUES (@SOID, @ProductID, @Price, @Quantity, @Amount, @Name)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SOID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SOID.Text;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@RefNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RefNo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProductID.ToString();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Price;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Quantity;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Amount;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name.ToString();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close():
    }
}
```

whenever i INSERT

ERROR occurs :

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
Line 215: decimal Price = decimal.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text);
```

The Amount has the same ERROR when i insert.

The price and amount values are formatted in my Gridview. `DataFormatString="Php {0:0.00}"`

What is incomplete in mt codes? what is wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is see is you are formating decimal with adding `Php` word at beginning. So, when you are trying to insert you will have a value as `Php 1.0` You need to replace this word and extra space, then try to convert it to decimal. You should get an output.

Comment: oh that's why. thank you for you consideration @Justcode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove word 'Php' from your amount value because 'Php' cannot be converted to decimal or int

```
decimal Price =    decimal.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.Replace("Php",""));
string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text.Replace("Php","");
```

you need to use decimal as amount to preserve precision values

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Amount);
```

Comment: thank you. i just thought i'll be okay to add a word there. thank you for answering and considering my question :D